# Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created -

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm getting this error on my ionic 3 app
I install angularfire 2 and firebase and declare configuration

```
app.module.ts

    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';


// import plugins
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';

import { config } from './app.firebaseconfig';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
//import components
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

// import providers
import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth/auth';
import { UserProvider } from '../providers/user/user';
import { ImghandlerProvider } from '../providers/imghandler/imghandler';





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{tabsPlacement: 'top'}), // placement the tabs in top
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config)

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    File,
    FilePath,
    FileChooser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthProvider,
    AngularFireAuth,
    UserProvider,
    ImghandlerProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

i have the config component I didn't import here.
when I add this line into imghandler provider

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

imghandler.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class ImghandlerProvider {
  nativepath: any;
  firestore = firebase.storage();

  constructor(public filechooser: FileChooser) {
  }

  uploadimage() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.filechooser.open().then((url) => {
          (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, (result) => {
            this.nativepath = result;
            (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.nativepath, (res) => {
              res.file((resFile) => {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
                reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
                  var imgBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
                  var imageStore = this.firestore.ref('/profileimages').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
                  imageStore.put(imgBlob).then((res) => {
                    this.firestore.ref('/profileimages').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                      resolve(url);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        reject(err);
                    })
                  }).catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                  })
                }
              })
            })
          })
      })
    })    
     return promise;   
  }
}
```

I got this error

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created -

I saw some solution in stackoverflow but these solution changes the initalizeapp with firebase.intializeApp but mine is AngularFireModule

Comment: hi, are you still working on this? Have you created an app in firebase and get the configuration? 

I see in your app.module.ts that you have this line: 
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config)

but you don't have a config variable. add that above the '@NgModule({' line.